# Using another phone's GPS signal as location

Tags: gps, geolocation, external-gps

I have an android phone (Device A), and an android tablet (Device B). Device B has a decent GPS, but Device A's is pretty much unusable. I would like to use Device A for navigation, but to do so I need a GPS quality only Device B has.

Is it possible to make Device A accept Device B's location as an external GPS signal (i.e. with the usage of mock location) while none of them being rooted? If not, does rooting Device A help?

*I am interested in a general answer, but also in a more device-specific one if it is better:

Device A: Prestigio 5517; Android 4.4

Device B: Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.4 WiFi; Android 5.0*

Comment: I've never tried that, but it should be possible. On device B you'd need an app to [Use your Droid as BT-GPS Mouse](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_externalgps#group_562), and on device A the corresponding counter-part to [Use an external GPS mouse](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_externalgps#group_561). Could you try and confirm that works?

Comment: @Izzy Confirmed. I tried a setup like this before without success, but I could make it work with [Bluetooth GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=googoo.android.btgps) on device A and [Bluetooth GPS Output](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meowsbox.btgps) on device B. Some other pairs also worked. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Another approach is tethering GPS with an app like [TetherGPS Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.comptonsoft.tgps_lite). It sounds more efficient since it can be more optimized, but this awaits confirmation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've made it an answer then, including details provided by you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a test confirmed, this is possible via corresponding apps:

- on the device providing the GPS signal ("B"), you will need an app to [Use your Droid as BT-GPS Mouse](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_externalgps#group_562). An approved candidate would be [Bluetooth GPS Output](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meowsbox.btgps) for this.
- on the device where you want to access that "external GPS" from ("A"), you'll need an app to [Use an external GPS mouse](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_externalgps#group_561). Approved candidate for that is [Bluetooth GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=googoo.android.btgps).

As you yourself found out, another approach is tethering GPS with an app like [TetherGPS Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.comptonsoft.tgps_lite) – which you write "sounds more efficient since it can be more optimized". As this waits your approval, please approve below this answer then :)